# HTML table set total columns width

Tags: html, css, layout

Does anyone know how to set total width of columns in HTML table?

I have a table with 2n columns (generated) and I want to set width of n columns with a specific value without:

- JS
- table-layout:fixed (some columns have to stretch with its content)
- nested table with colspan (table must be keep both column and row alignment)

E.g: I have 4 columns table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to group it with: Width Col 1 + Width Col 2 = 50% and Width Col 3 + Width Col 4 = 50% and Width of Col 1, 2, 3, 4 is auto.

Is it possible?

Comment: `td { width : 25% }`  ?

Comment: Thanks but it is not work as my expectation because column have dynamic width.

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  max-width:100%;
}
table td {
  max-width:25%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it not work in my case because I don't know exactly how big they are. It can be 1px < Col 2 < 50% and I don't know how many columns I can have (only know it is 2n).

Comment: @alex.tran - If this doesn't do the trick, why mark as answer and prevent others from perhaps seeing the question and answering with alternatives?

Comment: @BruceWayne ah, I don't know that mark have that behavior.